# First chance exception with pointer floating array

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("Enter the file name:\n");
    char inputFileLoc[100], outFileLoc[100];
    scanf("%s", inputFileLoc);
    int * n = 0;
    float rcoef[2];
    FILE * inFile = fopen("D:\\test.txt", "r");
    FILE * outFile = fopen(outFileLoc, "w");
    if (inFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found at %s", inputFileLoc);
    }
    else
    {

        printf("How many data points should we read in?");
        scanf("%i", &n);
        float *xdata = (float *)calloc(sizeof(float), *n);
        float *ydata = (float *)calloc(sizeof(float), *n); 
        for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++)
        {
            fscanf(inFile, "%f%f", &xdata[i], &ydata[i]);
        }
        fregression(xdata, ydata, rcoef);
        printf("Where would you like to save the file to?\n");
        scanf("%s", outFileLoc);
        fprintf(outFile, "The slope and intercept are %f and %f", rcoef[0], rcoef[1]);
        free(xdata);
        free(ydata);
    }
    fclose(inFile);
    fclose(outFile);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error at the line "float *xdata = (float *)..... and I have no idea why? Am I missing an exception handler of some sort because thats the only thing I can think of.

Comment: You want `n` to be an `int`, not an `int*`.

Comment: I'd say you should code in C and also tag this as C since this is more C than C++.

Comment: secretly C++ because he is casting malloc.

Comment: Or he's just writing in what Harbison & Steele call "Clean C", in which you always cast `malloc` and generally avoid doing things that won't compile in C++.

Comment: `scanf("%s", inputFileLoc);` --> `scanf("%s", outFileLoc);`

Comment: and `(float *)calloc(sizeof(float), *n)` --> `(float *)calloc(n, sizeof(float))`

Comment: `scanf("%s", outFileLoc);` --> `scanf(" %s", outFileLoc);` and meanless?

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
int * n = 0;
```

should be changed to

```
int n = 0;
```

`scanf` should get the address to write to and not a pointer's address. Even if you wanted to use a pointer, then memory should be allocated and `n` should point to that. In that case, you should drop the `&` to `n` when passing to `scanf` i.e. `scanf("%i", n);` should be fine.

Comment: Even with making your change it still gives the same error. I originally had what you had here before I changed it to the above code.

Comment: Why don't you do `std::cin >> n;`? What is the error it gives?

Answer (score 0):

1. change the **int *n** to **int n** as you scanf is trying to write into a memory which is not initialized.
2. In calloc also make the changes as it trying to assign from *n which is not defined properly

It works fine when i tried with two changes. even if you get errors after this specify your completely.